# Getting a path from the User with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

For my program I need to be able to get the path from the user so that my program downloads some files there.  I looked it up and found tkfiledialog, but I do not how i could get the string on a path using it.  Can someone please explain how I could use either tkfiledialog or something else to prompt the use to set a folder for a download location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
dirOpts = { 'initialdir': '/', 'mustexist': True, 'title': 'MyFileDialog' }
dirName = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(**dirOpts)
```